# How do I define an element that can either contain an integer or nothing at all?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

The question says it all! I want to have an XSD definition that makes it either possible to create an element like this

```
<Element>12345</Element>
```

or like  this

```
<Element></Element>
```

How do I do that?

I already tried using the `nillable` attribute and changing the element's type to `xs:string` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem creating a `xs:simpleType` and a `xs:restriction` with base `xs:string` concerning the `xs:minLength` with a value of 1.

```
<xs:simpleType name="type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```